# Hive QL what is the most efficient decision when filtering - using In ('') or Not In('')?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am running a query using Hive QL that is going to extract large volumes of data. 
In order to help it processing faster I am going to add a simple filter where column_a not in ('xxx'). However, what is the most efficient way of processing the query? using Not In or In? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If there is no partition by column_a then it does not matter, full scan will be performed, then filter applied.

Comment: As @leftjoin rightly said, full scan is performed on both cases unless there is a partition.

Answer (score 0):

Plain answer! Doesn't matter! The filtering of data will happen at Map side and whatever criteria you mention, is going to be applied to the data record by record to EVERY record. IN or NOT IN, every record in question will be evaluated in both the conditions. So use whatever is more intuitive!

All the best for your implementation.